# How to ignore some chars in Lucene Query (Hibernate Search)

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I have indexed this entity

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class MyBean {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Field
    private String foo;

    @Field
    private String bar;

    @Field
    private String baz;

}
```

for this schema:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id |     foo     |     bar     |     baz     |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 11 | an example  | ignore this | ignore this |
| 12 | ignore this | an e.x.a.m. | ignore this |
| 13 | not this    | not this    | not this    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I need to find `11` and `12` by searching for `exam`.

I tried with:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = 
    Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
    .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(MyBean.class).get();

Query textQuery = queryBuilder.keyword()
    .onFields("foo", "bar", "baz").matching("exam").createQuery();

fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(textQuery, MyBean.class).getResultList();
```

but this find only entity `11`, where I need also `12`. Is this possibile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a [`WordDelimiterFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html) with the `CATENATE_ALL` flag into your analysis chain, would be a likely solution.

So an analyzer implementation based on the `StandardAnalyzer` would look like this:

```java
public class StandardWithWordDelim extends StopwordAnalyzerBase{

    public static final CharArraySet STOP_WORDS_SET = StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET; 

    public StandardWithWordDelim() {
    }

    @Override
    protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName) {
        StandardTokenizer src = new StandardTokenizer();
        src.setMaxTokenLength(255);
        TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter(src);
        filter = new LowerCaseFilter(filter);
        filter = new StopFilter(filter, stopwords);
        //I'm inclined to add it here, so the abbreviation "t.h.e." doesn't get whacked by the StopFilter.
        filter = new WordDelimiterFilter(filter, WordDelimiterFilter.CATENATE_ALL, null);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(src, filter);
    }
}
```

It doesn't look like you are using the standard analyzer (NGrams perhaps?), but you should be able to figure that into your analysis somewhere.

Comment: Thank you @femtoRgon, the analyzer you suggested finds `e.x.a.m.` searching for `exam` and that's great! How can I extend it to find also partial words, i.e. find also `example` searching for `exam`, not requiring the use of wildcards?

Comment: Indexing ngrams would be a good way to do that.  See [NGramTokenFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/analyzers-common/index.html?org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenFilter.html).